# My action in observeEvent(input$button,...) is being overrun by the normal observe(...) in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I have a small R Shiny app that has two options for setting 4 `selectInput` fields. They can be selected manually, or through an action button that selects random values taken as a sample of 1 from the available choices in the 4 `selectInput` fields.

When I run my button with the code below, it works well, but then the choice is overwritten by a different value:

```
observeEvent(input$button1,  {

    x = sample(Fifa23$Full.Name,1)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Nationality",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Nationality),
                      selected = Fifa23$Nationality[Fifa23$Full.Name == x])
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Club",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Club[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality]),
                      selected = Fifa23$Club[Fifa23$Full.Name == x])
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Position",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Position[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality & Fifa23$Club==input$Club ]),
                      selected = Fifa23$Positions[Fifa23$Full.Name == x])
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Name",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Full.Name[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality & Fifa23$Club == input$Club & Fifa23$Position == input$Position]),
                      selected = Fifa23$Full.Name[Fifa23$Full.Name==x])    
    
  })
```

where my observe, for manual selection of selectInput() values as is follows:

```
observe({
    
    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateSelectInput(session, "Club",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Club[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality])
           )
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Position",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Position[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality & Fifa23$Club==input$Club ])
    )
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Name",
                      choices = unique(Fifa23$Full.Name[Fifa23$Nationality==input$Nationality & Fifa23$Club == input$Club & Fifa23$Position == input$Position])
)
    
  })
```

thank you for your help in advance.

I tried changing the arguments for Observe() like setting the suspend to TRUE, and the autoDestroy to TRUE, but I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: You mean the fields are updated on button press, but then are updated automatically soon after, without any user input?  Note that when you hit the button, the value of `input$Club` is changed, which will in turn trigger the observe statements.

Comment: Once you change value by the button the reactivty in Observe is triggered because you changed a value that should trigger a change in observe. You change input$Nationality so it has to run all observe that contain it. You have to create a reativeVal that will be true/false based on whether you want to trigger the observe or not.

Comment: Yes @AdagioMolto this is exactly the problem I am facing, and I am not sure why is it being changed to a new value. So even if it is getting changed based on the value of input$Club, it shouldn't change the randomly selected value of Full.Name

Comment: Thanks @jyr but can you explain how I should add this reactiveVal?

Comment: @DataAnalyst  you set defaul value to TRUE flag_value <- reactiveVal(TRUE) then at the end of observeEvent(input$button1 you set flat_value(FALSE) and in observe you will have if(flag_value() == TRUE) { do the thing } else { flag_value(TRUE) }, when you press the button observe will be suppressed and flag_value will be reset to default

Comment: @jyr I updated it as follows, but still facing the same issue: 

1) added the below on the top before any observe or observeEvent:  

  flag_value <- reactiveVal(TRUE) 
    
2) added this within each of the observes, before the action :

    if(flag_value()==TRUE){

3) added this at the end of each observe:

    else {flag_value(TRUE)}

4) added this in the end of the observeEvent(input$button1:

    flag_value(FALSE)

Comment: @DataAnalyst  I should have mentioned that you need a flag for each of the observes as it will get resettled once the observe is activated.

Comment: Check out this post and the posts linked within: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560439/shiny-update-input-without-reactives-getting-triggered . The method is pretty exactly what @jyr proposes.  Can't write a suggestion myself right now.